# NYC homeless shelter to housing application, food stamps required?

Tags: new-york-city, fair-housing-acts, public-accommodations

The question is in regards to one in a homeless shelter in the NYC system, which officially is supposed to help the people find some kind of government housing if that person is working etc and some other requirements.

The question is: is a member of a homeless shelter required to open a food stamps or cash assistance case in order to be eligible to start the housing application process?

Please respond with primary sources of the NYC law only, or at least places that cite the primary sources of the written law.

Not that the question is based off of a personal inquiry, but the reason I ask this question is because I am in a homeless shelter and the housing case worker said that I have to have a public assistance case open in order for them to start the application process, even though I already have Medicaid, which was said to only be SNAP or cash assistance, even though I am employed.

Again not asking about myself, but they said there's a law that requires all people applying to have a PA case (besides Medicaid) to be eligible to apply. Is this true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147447/discussion-between-yeets-and-michael-hall).

Comment: The State is running the program, they can, but are not required to define any or all or none of their requirements in statue.  It is unlikely that such a requirement would be made by statue, it’s too much of a minor detail. It is quite likely to be an administrative requirement, defined by policy by the agency.  With the expectation that if you need one, you need both, and if you don’t need one, you don’t need the other.

Comment: @jmoreno interesting. But can one have a fair hearing of one is heading difficulty getting a case open by food stamps but already has Medicaid or if one has philosophical reasons for not getting it?